# Simplifying three mass, two springs system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, solid-state-physics, spring

I have a system of three equal masses connected by two equal string system.

```
x_1      x_2       x_3
*--------*---------*           ------> x
M   k   M    k    M
```

Can I simplify this into a two mass (with 3/2 of the original mass each), one spring (with double the length) system, like so.

```
x_1              x_3
*-----------------*           ------> x
3/2M    k        3/2M
```

This is for an exercise regarding Solid State Physics (Classical Theory of the Harmonic Crystal)

I have the first setup in my exercise and with that I'd get three differential equations, but the examples in Aschroft are for two differential equations and it seems that the third is just trouble. I still have to calculate the frequency for the optical and acoustic branch, yet if I'd solve three DE's I'd get another branch, that would have not physical meaning.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Your two systems would have different numbers of normal modes, so I don't think you could usefully consider then equivalent.